# Guice test whether class has been created

Tags: java, unit-testing, dependency-injection, guice

I want to test whether during a test method an instance of an object is created from the injector. What is the best solution to achieve this goal.

```
@Test
public void testThingNotInstantiated() {
    AnotherThing another = new AnotherThing(); 
    // assert not instance of Thing created
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you simply want to check that Guice injects your `AnotherThing` you can write:

```
Injector injector

@Before {
    injector = Guice.createInjector(new AnotherThingModule());
}

@Test
public void testAnotherThingInstantiated() {
    //act
    AnotherThing another = injector.getInstance(AnotherThing.class);

    //assert
    assertNotNull(another);
}
```

If `AnotherThing` is a `@Singleton` and you want to test that Guice doesn't instantiate it twice you can write:

```
@Test
public void testSingletonAnotherThingNotInstantiatedTwiceByInjector() {
    //act
    AnotherThing first = injector.getInstance(AnotherThing.class);
    AnotherThing second = injector.getInstance(AnotherThing.class);

    //assert
    assertSame(first, second);
}
```